# Insert a row for each result of other query in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

If I have two tables with following columns:

```
Table1: [id,value]
Table2: [id,comment]
```

where id and value are numeric and comment is a string.

I need to retrieve all the ids with value>50 in the Table1.

And make an

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO table2 VALUES (id,"higher than 50");
```

for each one of those ids. How can I make it in MySQL? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO table2 
SELECT id,"higher than 50"
FROM Table1 where value > 50;
```